# ActionBarSherlock with fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there some way to hide status bar and keep action bar visible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is.
You should set `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` in your `onCreate` method of Activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Well, nope. I found another solution. Simply put this in an activity theme: <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> 
For ex. <style name="themeName" parent="parentName"><item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> </style>